# Launch function in a new thread with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, multithreading

I know there are lots of similar questions, but I've spent a lot of time making researches, and never found an easy answer to this.

I have a program doing simple stuff in NodeJS :

- it constantly scans some transactions, searching for keywords
- and when it finds the appropriate keyword, it launches a BUY order

(it's a crypto sniper bot :) )

For now, when the BUY order is launched, the main thread is stopped, and bot stops to scans transactions : I want to fix that.

---

My need is simple :

- when BUY order is created
- do NOT stop to scan transactions

--> what is the best way to do that ? Both "scan transactions" and "create BUY order" functions are in the same .js file (I could change that if it's mandatory)

---

So, is there a way to say :

- my main thread stays "scanning transactions" and never stops
- and when it's necessary, launch the "create BUY order" in a new thread ?

Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 1):

You can try `async` functions in Node.js. For example:

```js
const createBuyOrder = async (/* some args */) => {
    // create BUY order
}

// scanning thread
while (true) {
    if (/* it's necessary */) createBuyOrder();
}
```

It will start a new thread running function `createBuyOrder` when it's necessary.